# Timeout requests during Solr Commit

Tags: solr

If an update request sent to solr times out without a response is that request still fullfilled?

Answer (score 0):

You could query the server to find out if your document arrived. But if it does not answer, chances are, there has been some problem on the way to the server. If you can see the solr logs, you could find problems there.